# How to express mass calculation as a mathematical expression?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I have 300x300 gridded field with thickness values of a rock layer, and the field has a spatial resolution of dx = 25m and dy = 25m. In a next time step, the the thickness changes to the addition of a "inrock" value in the scheme. I calculate the weight of the rock layer in kg after 20 time steps. How can I express this in a mathematical expression involving integrals (rho = rock density)?

```
new_mass_rock(x,y) = 0
total_mass_rock(x,y) = 0
    for time = 1:20
        new_mass_rock(x,y) = rho_rock*(deltax*deltay*(inrock(x,y)));
        total_mass_rock(x,y) = total_mass_rock(x,y) + new_mass_rock(x,y);
    end
```

Comment: $$m(t)=\iint_{S} \rho|_{t=0}\,dx\,dy+\int_0^t \left(\iint_{S}\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}\,dx\,dy\right)\,dt=\iint_S \left(\rho|_{t=0}+\int_0^t\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}\,dt\right)\,dx\,dy$$

Comment: If $\rho$ is constant and thickness $h$ changes, then more correct record is $$m(t)=\rho\left(\iint_{S} h|_{t=0}\,dx\,dy+\int_0^t \left(\iint_{S}\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}\,dx\,dy\right)\,dt\right)=\rho\iint_S \left(h|_{t=0}+\int_0^t\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}\,dt\right)\,dx\,dy$$

Comment: You've used mathjax [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4485960/revisions); could you do the same here please?